# Accessing functions in object within child functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel really dumb asking this question, but I can't find a decent answer. I have an object of functions like so.

```
var methods = {
    init : function(){},
    one : function(){},
    two : function(){}
};
```

Let's say in function `one` I wanted to access function `two`. I know that I could do `methods.two()` and access it that way, but is there a a different way to do it, so I'm not referencing it from the outside, because that will get confusing with other parts of my code quickly.

Comment: `this.two()` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` operator as a reference to the object instance:

```js
var methods = {
    init : function(){ console.log('In INIT'); },
    one : function(){ console.log('In ONE');
                      this.two();
                    },
    two : function(){ console.log('In TWO');}
};

methods.one();
```